# How to get notification with Ajax and PHP when user submits data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Can I have ajax with PHP to get notification or alert when user submits form or data into mysql database?

In real time on server, it is obviously not recommended to refresh page/database every second. So, it is highly appreciated if someone helps me write an ajax/php code to get notification or alert when there is  a new row added in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

`You should create a Javascript function that fetch data from your php script or Database and then return them back to user asynchronously without refreshing the page.`

You would need to use ajax for refreshing a particular element of the page.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446219/how-work-ajax-notification-system-ajax-and-php) for more details.

Comment: Apologies, can you write one simple example for me. To get notification when there are new data in mysql. Thank you